# In "Pandora's Box", Heinlein says "odd genre" is a pun. How is it a pun?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, pronunciation

Robert Heinlein wrote an essay, "Pandora's Box", which was published as the introduction to *[The Worlds of Robert A. Heinlein](http://www.heinleinarchives.net/upload/index.php?_a=viewProd&productId=101)* (1965). In the second paragraph, he writes:

> Science fiction is not prophecy. It often reads as if it
> were prophecy; indeed the practitioners of this odd
> genre (pun intentional — I won’t do it again) of fiction
> usually strive hard to make their stories sound as if
> they were true pictures of the future. Prophecies.

I can't see how "odd genre" is a pun. What phrase is it meant to sound like?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is "Odd John" by Olaf Stapledon.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This appears to be a science-fiction writer in-joke. The same pun was called out by editor [James E. Gunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_E._Gunn) in his autobiography as having been made by Forrest Ackerman a decade earlier.

> I took the train back to Chicago sitting with Forrest (Forry) Ackerman, who gave me a quick course on fandom. He would write up that
> experience in a column he was writing for If, called “[The Odd Genre](https://archive.org/details/1956-04_IF_modified/page/n1/mode/2up)”
> **(a pun on Olaf Stapledon’s Odd John)**. That was the beginning of a long acquaintance.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star-Begotten: A Life Lived in Science Fiction](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34412690-star-begotten)</sup></sub>

Ackerman and Heinlein moved in similar circles, being published repeatedly in *If: Worlds of Science Fiction* over the years, so it's hardly surprising they'd share the same jokes with their editor and audience.

Comment: Agree completely that this is a reference to *Odd John* which dealt with a theme that Heinlein visited several times

Comment: @Andrew - Apparently Ackerman and Heinlein did *not* get along at all well, but they certainly were contemporaries and would have been influenced by each other and by Stapledon.

Comment: At first they were friendly
https://file770.com/how-did-i-not-know-this/

But later http://www.panshin.com/critics/Perry/perrynotes.html

"Heinlein .... discovered after its appearance that Forrest Ackerman had received money for supplying the text to the magazine. Heinlein demanded that Ackerman
turn over the money he had received, which Heinlein then donated to the Navy Relief. ... [A] scathing letter by Heinlein to Ackerman, dated November 17, 1973, and saying near the beginning: "Knock off the injured-innocence pose," .. concluding, "Keep your  hands off my property.""

Comment: Thanks! I really don't think it's a good pun though. "John" doesn't sound much like "genre", and the phrases aren't substitutable. You can't have a practitioner of an odd John. I'd have thought someone as skilled as Heinlein could do better.

Comment: @PhilvanKleur - Americans would pronounce it "Awd Jon-ruh" (with a hard-j), making it much closer to Odd John.

Comment: @Valorum Would we? Merriam-Webster, a popular American dictionary, [lists 'zhän-rə as the main pronunciation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genre), with 'jän-rə as only the fourth pronunciation. I agree with them: the zh sound at the start of genre is similar to the J in John, but it's not the same.

Comment: @PhilvanKleur It sounds like scifi author culture more than Heinlein's pun.

Comment: I agree with @amalloy, my (lifelong American English) pronunciation of "genre" starts off quite different from my pronunciation of "John". Much closer to a French pronunciation of "Jean", as in the main character from *Les Miserables*. That said, it wouldn’t surprise me if some common American pronunciations have changed in the last 70 years. The popularity of some European foods like croissants and lattes starting in the 1980s might have led a lot of Americans to try to pronounce words "more French", "more Italian", etc., to appear more sophisticated or worldly.

Comment: dzhan-ruh, or something like that, pronounced and heard

Comment: @PhilvanKleur, it was originally Ackerman's pun, not Heinlein's.

Comment: @PhilvanKleur - the word "genre" ("jean - ruh") begins very similarly to "john".  note too that most Americans would not really know how "genre" is really pronounced (eg In France), so it's perfectly clear and reasonable to see it as a clever pun.

Comment: It's rather a shame, given the context of science fiction being akin to prophecy I was really hoping for a pun on it being a "weird genre" instead.